# add scrollable option into multiselect jquery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, multi-select

I use dropdownlist in [this demo](http://www.jqueryfaqs.com/demos/112/). My list is larger than this demo that's why I want add scrollable option. How can I add scrollable option into dropdown

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the ul element in the example, you can simply set a fixed height and set the overflow-y property as scroll. For the example in your link;

```
ul {height:50px;overflow-y:scroll;}
```

Answer (score 32):

As per documentation.
Just add this parameter.
maxHeight: 450

e.g

```
$("#id").multiselect({
         enableFiltering: true,
         maxHeight: 450      
 });
```

Comment: I have answered as per the question. You need to add extra CSS and maybe js for mobile to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes found the solution from git issues, well it was an open bug. https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/1191. Bummer!

Comment: thanks for sharing the link for the issue. that would be helpful for other users.